# How to create a new ball every 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds) in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to JavaFX and I am creating a simple program. What I'm trying to achieve is to create a ball every 5 seconds that bounces off the walls and all balls should move every tens times per second (10 milliseconds). Also, feel free to leave other suggestions about my code.

Here's the source code:

public class Main extends Application {

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    //Sets the title, adds a group, and background color
    BorderPane canvas = new BorderPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(canvas, 640, 480, Color.WHITE);
    Circle ball = new Circle(10, Color.RED);
    ball.relocate(0, 10);
    
    canvas.getChildren().add(ball);
    
    stage.setTitle("Title");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
       
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(20), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        double dx = 5;                  //Step on x or velocity
        double dy = 3;                  //Step on y
            
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            //move the ball
            ball.setLayoutX(ball.getLayoutX() + dx);
            ball.setLayoutY(ball.getLayoutY() + dy);

            Bounds bounds = canvas.getBoundsInLocal();
                
            //If the ball reaches the left or right border make the step negative
            if(ball.getLayoutX() <= (bounds.getMinX() + ball.getRadius()) || 
                    ball.getLayoutX() >= (bounds.getMaxX() - ball.getRadius()) ){

                    dx = -dx;

                }

                //If the ball reaches the bottom or top border make the step negative
                if((ball.getLayoutY() >= (bounds.getMaxY() - ball.getRadius())) || 
                        (ball.getLayoutY() <= (bounds.getMinY() + ball.getRadius()))){

                    dy = -dy;

                }
                
            }
        }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: Hint: Keep a list of balls, and then loop through that list to update the position of each ball. Use a timer/thread to create new balls and add them to the list so that they canbe updated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it as suggested in comments:

- Create a custom object that holds the ball and its orientation information.
- Add the newly created object in the list and the ball in canvas.
- Loop through all balls and position them based on their orientation information.
- When your desired time is reached add a new ball.

To keep it simple, you don't need any concurrent related stuff. Maybe using them will improve the implementation (but I am not touching that now). :-)

Here is a demo of using the points I mentioned.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CanvasBallCreation_Demo extends Application {
    List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<>();
    BorderPane canvas;
    double dx = 5;                  //Step on x or velocity
    double dy = 3;                  //Step on y
    double refresh = 20;//ms
    double addBallDuration = 5000;//ms
    double temp = 0;
    SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        canvas = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(canvas, 640, 480, Color.WHITE);
        addBall();

        stage.setTitle("Title");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(refresh), e->moveBalls()));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
    }

    private void addBall(){
        Ball ball = new Ball();
        balls.add(ball);
        canvas.getChildren().add(ball.getBall());
    }

    private void moveBalls() {
        temp = temp + refresh;
        if(temp>addBallDuration){
            temp = 0;
            addBall();
        }
        Bounds bounds = canvas.getBoundsInLocal();
        balls.forEach(obj -> {
            Circle ball = obj.getBall();
            double tx = obj.getTx();
            double ty = obj.getTy();
            ball.setLayoutX(ball.getLayoutX() + dx*tx);
            ball.setLayoutY(ball.getLayoutY() + dy*ty);

            //If the ball reaches the left or right border make the step negative
            if (ball.getLayoutX() <= (bounds.getMinX() + ball.getRadius()) ||
                    ball.getLayoutX() >= (bounds.getMaxX() - ball.getRadius())) {
                obj.setTx(-tx);
            }

            //If the ball reaches the bottom or top border make the step negative
            if ((ball.getLayoutY() >= (bounds.getMaxY() - ball.getRadius())) ||
                    (ball.getLayoutY() <= (bounds.getMinY() + ball.getRadius()))) {
                obj.setTy(-ty);
            }
        });
    }

    class Ball {
        Circle ball = new Circle(10, Color.RED);
        double tx = 1;
        double ty = 1;
        public Ball(){
            // Placing the ball at a random location between 0,0 and 10,10 to generate random paths
            ball.relocate(rnd.nextInt(10), rnd.nextInt(10));
        }

        public Circle getBall() {
            return ball;
        }

        public double getTx() {
            return tx;
        }

        public void setTx(double tx) {
            this.tx = tx;
        }

        public double getTy() {
            return ty;
        }

        public void setTy(double ty) {
            this.ty = ty;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There are a few options, `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` or `Thread.sleep`.

You may want to look at both, and if you need two operations going at once (creating new balls, balls moving) I would look into using a new thread for each ball.

You can read more about using threads by using these articles, and your simple program actually seems like a great use case for learning about them.

```
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-in-java/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html
```

Comment: Threads do work with `JavaFX` but are probably the most complicated route. The first option one should look at in `JavaFX` is something from the `Animation` `API`. The second option should be [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm).